# IPV6 address format validation in Oracle 9i pl sql without using Reg exp function

Tags: oracle, plsql, ipv6, oracle9i

I am trying to validate the IPV6 address format input in my client application using PL/SQL in Oracle 9i. I searched in many places and what I can find says to use REGEXP_LIKE, but this is not supported in Oracle 9i:

```
if ( /* IPv6 expanded */ 
     REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}\z', 'i') 
     /* IPv6 shorthand */
     OR (NOT REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A(.?[a-f0-9](:|\z)){8}', 'i') 
     AND REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A([a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,6})?::([a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a‌​-f0-9]{1,4}){0,6})?\‌​z', 'i'))
) then
```

To achieve this am using the regular expression shown above but I am getting error message "PLS-00201: identifier 'REGEX_LIKE' must be declared". Can anyone suggest how to implement same validation in Oracle 9i compatible PL/SQL?

I am trying to store IPV6 address of format `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/yyy` where min and max value of `xxxx` is between 0000 to FFFF and `yyy` between 0 to 128.

Comment: Something like [this](http://phil-sqltips.blogspot.nl/2009/06/regexpreplace-regexplike-for-oracle-9i.html)?

Comment: @Shekhar - Same as what? Please give an example of what you tried and how it doesn't fit your case. Just plain asking for a solution means either two things: 1. You didn't search the Internet for a solution. 2. You didn't even tried and you're asking for a solution right away. At least state what you've tried and only then someone might help you.

Comment: @JeroenHeier - Am using below snippet to validate the format of IPV6 but am getting error as

Error(8,5): PLS-00201: identifier 'REGEX_LIKE' must be declared

if (
    /* IPv6 expanded */
    REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}\z', 'i')
    /* IPv6 shorthand */
    OR (NOT REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A(.*?[a-f0-9](:|\z)){8}', 'i')
        AND REGEX_LIKE(v, '\A([a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,6})?::([a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,6})?\z', 'i'))
     ) then

Comment: Please edit the question to include this. It is unreadable in a comment.